# Как правильно подключать браузер к PHP-демону по WebSocket?

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Начал изучать веб-сокеты... Написал сервер на PHP, который обрабатывает сообщения определённого формата. Сервер отлично работает с клиентом на C++, который просто коннектится на нужный порт localhost-а и начинает обмен данными. Но с браузером беда...
Сервер пишет, что Client connected... Но браузер не просто коннектится, а сразу шлёт HTTP-заголовки с Connection Upgrade и т.д. Естественно эти заголовки сервер никак не обрабатывает, так как ждёт сообщение другого формата, и в консоли браузера я вижу отправленные заголовки и бесконечное получение ответа. Естественно ожидаемый `alert("Connection established");` не появляется

**Я должен вручную обрабатывать эти заголовки?** Может что-то не так делаю? Как автоматизировать эту браузерную формальность upgrade-а на WS?

Comment: Не пишите ответ в вопросе. Лучше добавьте свой ответ и отметьте его галочкой. Так за него смогут проголосовать другие и вопрос не будет висеть как "без ответов".

Answer (score 0):

**Всё, разобрался!**

```
define('WS_GIUD', '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11');
define('WS_KEY_MARKER', 'Sec-WebSocket-Key: ');
...
switch ($Data[0]){
    case 'G': // GET / HTTP ...
        $KeyStart = strpos($Data, WS_KEY_MARKER); // 'Sec-WebSocket-Key: '
        if ($KeyStart){
            $KeyStart += strlen(WS_KEY_MARKER);
            $SecureKey = substr($Data, $KeyStart, strpos($Data, 0x0D0A, $KeyStart) - $KeyStart - 1);
            $Handshake = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
                        ."Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                        ."Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                        ."Sec-WebSocket-Accept: ".base64_encode(sha1($SecureKey.WS_GIUD, true))."\r\n\r\n";
            socket_write($Socket, $Handshake);
        }
        else{
            socket_close($Socket);
            unset($Clients[$Socket_key]);
            break;
        }
        break;
```